# PHP Path in my folders

Tags: php

im with a problem with my php paths, i hope someone can explain what its happening

this are my folders

```
index.php
   configs.php
     infos.php
     db_connect.php (db_connect.php have an include to infos.php)
   login
     functions.php (this functions php have an include to db_connect.php)
```

Im using some ajax to do stuff, and all of that its working, but when i tried to call the functions.php to my index

```
include('login/functions.php');
```

i got this error:

```
( ! ) Warning: require_once(C:\wamp\www\****\public\login\configs\db_connect.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\****\public\login\functions.php on line 2


( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\****\public\login\configs\db_connect.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\****\public\login\functions.php on line 2
```

I know that we have a lot of posts with this issue and i tried a lot of them, but without sucess..

i tried to use in the paths

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
dirname(__FILE__);
basename(__FILE__);
```

but.. well still have the same problem, can someone explain me how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `configs.php` in your top snippet should be `configs/`,
so you have this structure:

```
public/
  index.php
  configs/
    infos.php
    db_connect.php
  login/
    functions.php
```

In `functions.php`, do

```
include __DIR__ . '/../configs/db_connect.php'
```

You can easily find out what include path you need in this case by changing to the directory where the `functions.php` php file is located:

```
cd C:\wamp\www\****\public\login\
```

and double-checking if the functions.php is indeed here:

```
dir functions.php
```

and then finding the proper relative path:

```
dir ..\configs\db_connect.php
```